# Clickonce with .Net Core Console Application

Tags: .net-core, clickonce

I built a project with Visual Studio 2017 as Core Consol application. I want to publish a clickonce application. My project must works all platform Windows, Linux and Mac. And can works as a clickonce app. Can I do .NET Core Console Application as clickonce? And how can I do it?